# Meaning of "off" in this context

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> “Yes, yes! I deny it!” Esmeralda cried out.
>   The judge sneered. “Then how do you
>   explain the charges being made against you?”
>   “I cannot explain them, sir. I only know
>   that I am innocent. I love Phoebus! It was a
>   priest—the priest who keeps following me.”
>   The judge became restless. “Very well. I’ve
>   heard enough of your lies. **Off** to the torture
>   chamber! You’ll soon change your story.

Dose it mean: go out?

Answer (score 1):

"Off to" indicates the beginning of a journey.

"We're off to Bognor" would mean that the speaker (and presumably some friends) were just going to Bognor. It would seem most natural at the beginning of the journey, but in some dialects it would also be used at any point on the journey, meaning "we're on our way to Bognor".

"Off you go" is an instruction to someone to set out on some journey, or sometimes to start some activity.

"Off to X!" is generally an order to go somewhere, but might be a joyous exclamation made in the Bognor example. As everyone piled into the car, someone might lean out of a window, thrust an arm into the air, and yell enthusiastically, "off to Bognor!". In context here, of course, it's an instruction given quite caustically.

Comment: My mother used to say "Off to bed!" when I was little.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Exactly so. And if you want to be cliched, and she was mad at you, she might have added "without any supper" ;)

Comment: @SamBC: Thanks alot. So can we say in this context it mean: go out to torture room

Comment: More "go to the torture room, now", but yeah.